# Cookie set with JavaScript not persisted by Safari IOS after closing the app

Tags: ios, cookies, mobile-safari

I try to set a cookie with JavaScript . Let's say cookie name `publish` with value `on`. Everything works great and the cookie is stil there after refresh.

My probleme is that after closing Safari (IOS 11) and open again the page that cookie is not there anymore. Other cookies added by third party are there.

Question: Why is my Safari forgetting my specific cookie.

P.S
I do not have active any block cookies or block third party cookies.
I do not have any problems on desktop browsers

Comment: next time, don't forget to add javascript tag also.

Comment: You should show what you do exactly, especially since as you point out, cookies of other sites are working correctly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming

Comment: I don't agree, Yvette. How is it not about programming?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) when adding cookie you need to specify either `max-age` or `expires` parameter option. If neither expires nor max-age specified it will expire at the end of session (when you quit the browser).

```
document.cookie = "temporary=hello";
document.cookie = "permanent=world;max-age=31536000"; // 60*60*24*365, for a year
```

Comment: Beware max age is capped to 7 days now: https://webkit.org/blog/8613/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-1/